# Go, Golang : fetchall for go MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, go

I am using the go-mysql-driver https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

I am looking for something like the following in Python:

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(sql)
result = c.fetchall()
for elem in result:
  list.append(elem[i])
return list
```

And the only thing that comes to my mind is:

```
result, err := conn.Exec(query)
// func (db *DB) Exec(query string, args ...interface{}) (Result, error)
```

I want to traverse through the results from the Exec method and then fetch the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in the result you should use `Query()` instead of `Exec()`:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age=?", age)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close();
for rows.Next() {
  var name string
  if err := rows.Scan(&name); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("%s is %d\n", name, age)
}
```